# Autocalculation Java Script doesnt work in other modal

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I try to make some auto calculation in fetching array data with pop up modal, technically javascript just work in the first record of data, but the others didn't work.. can you help me to solve this issue?

Here my html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="" >
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group first-column">
         <label>Bulan
         </label>
         <select class="form-control" name="bulan">
            <option selected="selected">Pilih Bulan</option>
            <?php
               $bulan=array("Januari","Februari","Maret","April","Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember");
               $jlh_bln=count($bulan);
               for($c=0; $c<$jlh_bln; $c+=1){
                   echo"<option value=$bulan[$c]> $bulan[$c] </option>";
               }
               ?>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group second-column">
         <label>Tahun
         </label>
         <?php
            $now=date('Y');
            echo "<select class='form-control' name=tahun>";
            for ($a=2015;$a<=$now;$a++)
            {
                 echo "<option value='$a'>$a</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group ">
      <label>ID Karyawan
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="cname" name="p_idkaryawan" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>" disabled>
      <input class="form-control" id="cname" name="p_idkaryawan" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['id'];?>" hidden>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Nama Lengkap
      </label>
      <input class=" form-control" id="cname" name="nama" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['nama'];?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Gaji Pokok
      </label>
      <input class=" form-control" id="txt1" name="nama" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['gapok'];?>" disabled>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group first-column">
         <label>Tarif Lembur
         </label>
         <input class=" form-control"  id="txt2"  onkeyup="sum();" name="nama" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['lembur'];?>" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group second-column">
         <label>Jumlah Lembur
         </label>
         <input class=" form-control"  id="txt3"  onkeyup="sum();" name="jumlahlembur" type="text" placeholder="satuan hari">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Tunjangan Jabatan
      </label>
      <input class=" form-control" id="txt4" onkeyup="sum();"name="tunjangan" type="text" placeholder="beri angka 0 jika tidak ada">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Bonus
      </label>
      <input class=" form-control" id="txt5" onkeyup="sum();"name="bonus" type="text" placeholder="beri angka 0 jika tidak ada">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Total Gaji Bulan
      </label>
      <input class=" form-control" id="txt6" name="totalgaji" type="text" >
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="pull-right">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="simpan">Simpan</button>
         <button class="btn btn-warning"
            data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"
            type="button">
         <i class="fa fa-times">
         </i>
         Cancel
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

here my JS code :

```
    <script>
function sum() {
      var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
      var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
       var txttigaNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt3').value;
        var txtempatNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt4').value;
         var txtlimaNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt5').value;
          var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + (parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue) * parseInt(txttigaNumberValue)) + parseInt(txtempatNumberValue) + parseInt(txtlimaNumberValue);
      if (!isNaN(result)) {

         document.getElementById('txt6').value = result;

      }
}
</script>
```

Thanks before

---